# Alexa Skill using the Voice code

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I wanted to add additional security to all the voice request given to Alexa after account linking. I have seen some skill app using the personal pin which they can utter to say who they are, also I see echo has this Voice code which can be used for voice purchase.

Now my question is instead of creating my own solution to use personal pin and maintain it, is there a way to use the Alexa's Voice code in my skill? Also I wanted to make sure the user utters this voice code everytime he asks something to the skill.

Please let me know how this can be achieved or is there any alternate way to do this?

Also to mention the skill I am developing is not related to purchase anything but just wanted this as additional security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently are not any built-in slots or intents to perform user authentication. You certainly can define your own slot to allow a user to provide a word or number. Your code will then need to handle validating the user with it, using your own database or REST server.